# Replacing Hypothesis Testing with Regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model

It appears, unless I am misunderstanding something fundamental, there is a way to preform hypothesis testing using a linear model instead. Is there any simple source (book?) that shows how to do this? For example, we have a population of two different samples and we want to compare their means. How does a linear model approach substitute a classical hypothesis test procedure?

Comment: You might find this helpful.  https://lindeloev.github.io/tests-as-linear/

Comment: You write " preform hypothesis testing using a linear model instead"  Instead of what?

and  "How does a linear model approach substitute a classical hypothesis test procedure?"   A linear model is pretty classic. If you mean compared to a t-test, well, a t-test is a linear model.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you are asking specifically about conducting a two-sample test with a continuous endpoint - what would traditionally be taught as a "T-test". So can we test the same hypothesis as a T-test with linear regression? Even better, the T-test *is* linear regression. The standard OLS model is written:

$$ Y = \alpha + \beta X + \epsilon $$

Where $\alpha$ is an intercept, $X$ is a covariate of interest, $\beta$ is a slope and $\epsilon$ \is a random error, $Y$ is the response. If $X$ is taken to be a 0/1 indicator, or a "dummy" variable for group membership for the $Y$ vector. Then the "slope" $\beta$ is a difference of means between the two groups. In other words, the hypothesis $\mathcal{H}_0 : \mu_1 - \mu_0$ is the same as $\mathcal{H}_0: \beta = 0 $. The below visual aid helps to understand. Using R,

```
with(sleep, abline(extra ~ as.numeric(group)))
with(sleep, abline(lm(extra ~ as.numeric(group))))
```

The rise of the line of best fit over a unit length estimates the difference of means.

[image]

Under an equal variance assumption identical inference is obtained (a classical OLS assumption)

```
> t.test(extra ~ group, data=sleep, var.equal=TRUE)

    Two Sample t-test

data:  extra by group
t = -1.8608, df = 18, p-value = 0.07919
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means between group 1 and group 2 is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -3.363874  0.203874
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
           0.75            2.33
```

compared to the linear model result

```
> summary(lm(extra ~ group, data=sleep))

Call:
lm(formula = extra ~ group, data = sleep)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-2.430 -1.305 -0.580  1.455  3.170 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   0.7500     0.6004   1.249   0.2276  
group2        1.5800     0.8491   1.861   0.0792 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.899 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1613,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1147 
F-statistic: 3.463 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.07919
```

There are a remarkable number of generalizations here where they are approximately (meaning very closely) the same as other regression findings. For instance, the unequal variance assumption typically uses Welch's Degrees of Freedom with Satterthwaite correction - this is merely *a solution* (not *the solution*) to the Fisher Behren's problem. You can also use Robust Sandwich Error estimation in the linear model to account for unequal variance (yet another solution). For a categorical covariate, the Chi-square test of heterogeneity is the score test of a logistic regression with a bivariate regressor. For time to event, the log rank test is the score test of the Cox proportional hazards model. Using regression for these simple problems is entirely cogent.